# Binning Continuous Variables By Entropy From Binary Response (R)

Tags: r, entropy, binning

I am working with at data set where the goal is to predict a binary response. I have a few continuous variable that I think would be beneficial to bin. I was reading this idea about entropy based binning - http://kevinmeurer.com/a-simple-guide-to-entropy-based-discretization/. I have looked around and found `entropy` and `infotheo` - in these packages it doesn't look like the methods actually use the response to bin continuous features based on the response.

My question is how can I achieve this in R?

Comment: The R package logiBin can be used to bin continuous variables using the function getBins.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to bin your continuous variables beforehand? Can't you just do logistic regression? Seems to be better suited for your problem and then you wouldn't need to discretize. Perhaps you can share a part of your data here, so we can better help you.

Comment: Discretization is used if you want to lose important predictive information and introduce arbitrariness into the analysis.  I have trouble understanding why those are good goals to have.

Answer (score 1):

The R package discretize includes the function `mdlp`.

The RWeka package includes the function `Discretize`.

Both refer to the [This paper](http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/algorithm/congreso/fayyad1993.pdf):

> U. M. Fayyad and K. B. Irani (1993). Multi-interval discretization of
>   continuous-valued attributes for classification learning. Thirteenth
>   International Joint Conference on Artificial Intelligence, 1022–1027.
>   Morgan Kaufmann.